# How to resolve the following oracle error?

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, oracle11g, weka

I am using weka and oracle 11g r2 as my database to store the decision trees for id3 based incremental learning.After configuring weka and oracle,with necessary edits am getting the following error.Please help me resolve it as my project deadline is coming soon.Thanks in advance!!!!!!!

```
in start1java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with     the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor


java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could   not establish the connectionin bothjava.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Comment: You need to have a service name defined in tnsnames.ora file and a valid listener in listener.ora file. 
This
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/listener.htm
and
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora

After the changes You need to restart the oracle service.
It should help if that's the problem.

Comment: I think jdbcUrl needs to be properly set in some props file (most likely DatabaseUtils.props).      jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<HostNameRunningOracle>:1521:<DatabaseInstance> ,       The port number is usually 1521.  If you take a look at the tnsnames.ora file that is being used to connect to Oracle using Sql*Plus, etc., it provides these details, like Database Instance. etc.